# How to create vector embeddings using SentenceTransformers?

Tags: python, openaiembeddings

I found this code: https://github.com/pixegami/langchain-rag-tutorial/blob/main/create_database.py

It takes the document, splits it into chunks, creates vector embeddings for each chunk, and saves those into Chroma Database. However, the source code uses OpenAI key to create embeddings. Since I don't have access to OpenAI I tried to use free alternative, - SentenceTransformers. But I wasn't able to rewrite the code properly.

Here is my curent attempt:

```
from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.schema import Document
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from langchain.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma
import os
import shutil

CHROMA_PATH = "chroma"
DATA_PATH = "data/books"

embedder = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

def main():
    generate_data_store()

def generate_data_store():
    documents = load_documents()
    chunks = split_text(documents)
    save_to_chroma(chunks)

def load_documents():
    loader = DirectoryLoader(DATA_PATH, glob="*.md")
    documents = loader.load()
    return documents

def split_text(documents: list[Document]):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
        chunk_size=300,
        chunk_overlap=100,
        length_function=len,
        add_start_index=True,
    )
    chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    print(f"Split {len(documents)} documents into {len(chunks)} chunks.")

    document = chunks[10]
    print(document.page_content)
    print(document.metadata)

    return chunks

def save_to_chroma(chunks: list[Document]):
    # Clear out the database first.
    if os.path.exists(CHROMA_PATH):
        shutil.rmtree(CHROMA_PATH)

    # Create a new DB from the documents.
    db = Chroma.from_documents(
        chunks, embedder.encode, persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH
    )
    db.persist()
    print(f"Saved {len(chunks)} chunks to {CHROMA_PATH}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/andrew/Simple Tom/Robotics/Crew_AI/langchain-rag-tutorial/create_database.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/andrew/Simple Tom/Robotics/Crew_AI/langchain-rag-tutorial/create_database.py", line 15, in main
    generate_data_store()
  File "/media/andrew/Simple Tom/Robotics/Crew_AI/langchain-rag-tutorial/create_database.py", line 20, in generate_data_store
    save_to_chroma(chunks)
  File "/media/andrew/Simple Tom/Robotics/Crew_AI/langchain-rag-tutorial/create_database.py", line 49, in save_to_chroma
    db = Chroma.from_documents(
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 778, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 736, in from_texts
    chroma_collection.add_texts(
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 275, in add_texts
    embeddings = self._embedding_function.embed_documents(texts)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'embed_documents'
```

I'm not a programmer. If someone could point out if it's at all possible to achive this without OpenAI key and if yes, then where my mistake is, that'd be great.

Comment: could you add the full error traceback? it's not cleat which line raised that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define your `embedding` model, with `HuggingFaceEmbeddings`

```py
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embedder = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name = "sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2"
)
```

2. Then embed the chunks into vectorDB

```py
    db = Chroma.from_documents(
        documents=chunks, 
        embedding=embedder, 
        persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH
    )
    db.persist()
```